# How to set badges on app icon when app is in minimize mode?

Tags: objective-c

When application is in minimize state and at the same time notifications come then badges should be see on  app icon.

Answer (score 0):

If a notification arrives and your application is not is foreground, the OS handles the notification.

Your notification can have a field `badge` that will make the OS update the badge. However, this means that the server than sends the notification must have a way of knowing which number should be the badge.

The notification body would look like this:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "badge" : 9
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres my solution. I needed to achieve the same thing in an app that I did. I had a queue of Downloads and wanted to use a Badge to show how many downloads were left, and keep updating it even while in the background. Basically my solution was, every time one of the downloads were completed I setup a `UILocalNotification` with a silent sound, and no message text. Simply just set the badge..As seen below..

```
- (void)queRequestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {

    self.inResourceCount -= 1; // Deducted 1 from the total count of downloads in queue.

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil) {

    UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
    notif.fireDate = [NSDate  date]; // Schedule notification for now.
    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notif.soundName = @"silence.caf";
    notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = inResourceCount; // Number you want displayed as Badge.

    // This is where the magic happens, and actually changes your badge.    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];

    [notif release];
   }

}
```

Id like to point out, that my scenrio may be different from yours. I was using `ASIHTTPRequest` library, which has support for continuing downloads while backgrounded, and the method above `queRequestFinished:` is called even while in the background. Hope this helps, if it does mark it as the answer :) .